# How to create OpenCL command queue?

Tags: c, opencl

I'm trying to learn OpenCL but I can't even make a simple kernel to work.

The code below comes from the book "OpenCL Programming by Example", which I modified, modified, modified... and still, I have no clues what's the problem.

Every time I execute the program in my PC (AMD Athlon 5350 APU with Radeon R3), it prints the result as "0.0000".
If I run the same executable, in my other machine (which is a clone of this HD, so everything is the same) with a NVIDIA 1080 TI, the program outputs "3.000"  as the result.

I noticed a warning in the compiler output, so I  changed the obsolete clCreateCommandQueue call to clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties().

And now... it just segfaults (with a printf() test I know it segfaults during/after the clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties).

On the system with the NVIDIA GPU, it just works.

What am I missing?

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#include <CL/cl.h>

#define VECTOR_NS 4096
#define VECTOR_SIZE (VECTOR_NS*sizeof(float))

static const char* saxpy_kernel =
    "__kernel void saxpy_kernel(__global float *A, __global float *B, __global float *C)\n"
    "{\n"
        "int index = get_global_id(0);\n"
        "C[0] = 3;\n"
    "}\n"
    ;

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    float total;
    float* A;
    float* B;
    float* C;
    float* Cmapped;
    cl_mem Acl;
    cl_mem Bcl;
    cl_mem Ccl;
    cl_context context;
    cl_platform_id* platforms;
    cl_uint num_platforms;
    cl_uint num_devices;
    cl_command_queue queue;
    cl_kernel kernel;
    cl_int clStatus;

    // Get platform and device information
    platforms = NULL;
    //Set up the Platform
    clStatus = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &num_platforms);
    platforms = (cl_platform_id *)malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id)*num_platforms);
    clStatus = clGetPlatformIDs(num_platforms, platforms, NULL);
    //Get the devices list and choose the device you want to run on
    cl_device_id* device_list = NULL;

    clStatus = clGetDeviceIDs( platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 0, NULL, &num_devices);
    device_list = (cl_device_id *) malloc(sizeof(cl_device_id)*num_devices);

    clStatus = clGetDeviceIDs( platforms[0], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, num_devices, device_list, NULL);
    // Create one OpenCL context for each device in the platform
    context = clCreateContext( NULL, num_devices, device_list, NULL, NULL, &clStatus);

    /* Create the command queue */
    //queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_list[0], 0, &clStatus);
    queue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(context, device_list[0], NULL, &clStatus);

    if(clStatus != CL_SUCCESS){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to execute the kernel: %d.\n", clStatus);
        exit(1);
    }

    /* */
    if((A = aligned_alloc(sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE), VECTOR_SIZE)) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if((B = aligned_alloc(sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE), VECTOR_SIZE)) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if((C = aligned_alloc(sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE), VECTOR_SIZE)) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to allocate memory.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Initialize it */
    i = 0;
    do {
        A[i] = 1;
        B[i] = 2;
        C[i] = 0;
    } while(++i != VECTOR_NS);

    Acl = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, VECTOR_SIZE, A, &clStatus); // CL_MEM_READ_ONLY
    Bcl = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, VECTOR_SIZE, B, &clStatus); // CL_MEM_READ_ONLY
    Ccl = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, VECTOR_SIZE, C, &clStatus); // CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY

    // Create a program from the kernel source
    // Build the program
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char**)&saxpy_kernel, NULL, &clStatus);

    if(clStatus != CL_SUCCESS){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to compile the OpenCL code.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    clStatus = clBuildProgram(program, 1, device_list, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    if(clStatus != CL_SUCCESS){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to compile the OpenCL code.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Create the OpenCL kernel
    kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "saxpy_kernel", &clStatus);
    // Set the arguments of the kernel
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&Acl);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&Bcl);
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&Ccl);

    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
    size_t global_size = VECTOR_NS; // Process the entire lists
    size_t local_size = 1;

    // Process one item at a time
    clStatus = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &global_size, &local_size, 0, NULL, NULL);

    if(clStatus != CL_SUCCESS){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to execute the kernel: %d.\n", clStatus);
        exit(1);
    }

    //* Clean up and wait for all the comands to complete. */
    clFlush(queue);

    /* Display the result to the screen */
    Cmapped = (float*) clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, Ccl, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, VECTOR_SIZE, 0, NULL, NULL, &clStatus); // CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR

    if(clStatus != CL_SUCCESS){
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: failed to execute the kernel: %d.\n", clStatus);
        exit(1);
    }

    total = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < VECTOR_NS; i++)
        total += C[i];

    printf("TOTAL: %f\n", total);

    /* Clean up and wait for all the comands to complete. */
    clFlush(queue);
    clFinish(queue);

    /* Finally release all OpenCL allocated objects and host buffers. */
    clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    clReleaseMemObject(Acl);
    clReleaseMemObject(Bcl);
    clReleaseMemObject(Ccl);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
    clReleaseContext(context);

    free(platforms);
    free(device_list);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you use `clEnqueueReadBuffer` instead of `clEnqueueMapBuffer` does it work? Also, I see you are writing to _only_ c[0] but then summing up all values. What values do you think you get from c[1] to c[VECTOR_NS-1]? Maybe uninitialized memory.

Comment: This source was my attempt to learn OpenCL thread groups, ids... to confirm if I was understanding it well.
As nothing was working, I edited and edited while looking for the problem... and finally now the kernel just does "C[0] = 3" (with everything else initialized to 0).
This is just a test, not doing anything useful.

Comment: I'm not trying to use clEnqueueReadBuffer() because my entire goal is to use a 16GB  computer with an APU with zero-copy... I'm a newbie on OpenCL but I followed the tutorial at https://arrayfire.com/zero-copy-on-integrated-gpus.
The tutorial is on C++ but I think I've perfectly adapted to the C version of the API.

Comment: I see the init now. I don't know why it's not working. Please check the clStatus values returned from clCreateBuffer to make sure everything is cool with you CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR usage (although it's probably not that because it would cause errors downstream). An alternative method is to use CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, then map before init and unmap before kernel (then map again to get results). The reason clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties might be failing on your AMD is the version of that driver doesn't support it. Check the platform and device versions (by code or using clInfo).

Comment: It is possible that one of the driver's implementation of the create command queue call attempts to de-reference the nullptr (for the queue properties). If you define the properties, does it work? Try an empty list for starters, using cl_queue_properties properties[] = {0}; and replacing your NULL.

Answer (score 0):

While your code works as-is on my machine, I think is a possible issue that could cause your problem. The call

```
Cmapped = (float*)clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, Ccl, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, 0, VECTOR_SIZE, 0, NULL, NULL, &clStatus);
```

changes `Cmapped` but you try to read from the original `C` buffer in

```
total = 0;
for(i = 0; i < VECTOR_NS; i++)
    total += C[i];
```

This should probably read

```
total = 0;
for(i = 0; i < VECTOR_NS; i++)
    total += Cmapped[i];
```

However, since you created the buffer with the `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` flag, your OpenCL driver should also be able to optimize the copy operation if you use `clEnqueueReadBuffer` instead, if you use the original pointer as the destination:

```
clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, Ccl, CL_TRUE, 0, VECTOR_SIZE, C, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

This should be a no-op if the data has not been cached to device memory by the OpenCL implementation.