# Segfault when using clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm trying to write an OpenCL wrapper in C++.
Yesterday I was working on my Windows 10 machine (NVIDIA GTX970 Ti, latest NVIDIA GeForce drivers I believe) and my code worked flawless.

Today, I'm trying it out on my laptop (Arch Linux, AMD Radeon R7 M265, Mesa 17.3.3) and I get a segfault when trying to create a command queue.

Here's the GDB backtrace:

```
#0  0x00007f361119db80 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libMesaOpenCL.so.1
#1  0x00007f36125dacb1 in clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties () from /usr/lib/libOpenCL.so.1
#2  0x0000557b2877dfec in OpenCL::createCommandQueue (ctx=..., dev=..., outOfOrderExec=false, profiling=false) at /home/***/OpenCL/Util.cpp:296
#3  0x0000557b2876f0cf in main (argc=1, argv=0x7ffd04fcdac8) at /home/***/main.cpp:27
#4  0x00007f361194cf4a in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x0000557b2876ecfa in _start ()
```

(I've censored part of the paths)
Here's the code that's producing the error:

```
CommandQueue createCommandQueue(Context ctx, Device dev, bool outOfOrderExec, bool profiling) noexcept
{
    cl_command_queue_properties props [3]= {CL_QUEUE_PROPERTIES, 0, 0};

    if (outOfOrderExec)
    {
        props[1] |= CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE;
    }

    if (profiling)
    {
        props[1] |= CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE;
    }

    int error = CL_SUCCESS;

    cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties(ctx.get(), dev.get(), props, &error);

    if (error != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error while creating command queue: " << OpenCL::getErrorString(error) << std::endl;
    }

    CommandQueue commQueue = CommandQueue(queue);
    Session::get().registerQueue(commQueue);

    return commQueue;
}
```

The line with `clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties` is where the segfault happens.

`Context` is a wrapper class for a `cl_context`, `Context::get()` returns the original cl_context:

```
class Context
{
    private:
        ...
        cl_context context;

    public:
        ...

        cl_context get() const noexcept;

        ...
};
```

`Device` is a wrapper for `cl_device`, `Device::get()` also returns the cl_device:

```
class Device
{
    private:
        ...

        cl_device_type type;
        cl_device_id id;

    public:
        ...

        cl_device_id get() const noexcept;

        cl_device_type getType () const noexcept;

        ...
};
```

Here's the main function:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv [])
{
    OpenCL::Session::get().init();

    for (const std::string& deviceAddress : OpenCL::Session::get().getAddresses())
    {
        std::cout << "[" << deviceAddress << "]: " << OpenCL::Session::get().getDevice(deviceAddress);
    }

    OpenCL::Context ctx = OpenCL::getContext();

    std::cout << "OpenCL version: " << ctx.getVersionString() << std::endl;

    OpenCL::Kernel kernel = OpenCL::createKernel(OpenCL::createProgram("src/Kernels/Hello.cl", ctx), "SAXPY");
    OpenCL::CommandQueue queue = OpenCL::createCommandQueue(ctx, OpenCL::Session::get().getDevice(ctx.getAssociatedDevices()[0]));

    unsigned int testDataSize = 1 << 13;

    std::vector <float> a = std::vector <float> (testDataSize);
    std::vector <float> b = std::vector <float> (testDataSize);

    for (int  i = 0; i < testDataSize; i++)
    {
        a[i] = static_cast<float>(i);
        b[i] = 0.0;
    }

    OpenCL::Buffer aBuffer = OpenCL::allocateBuffer(ctx, a.data(), sizeof(float), a.size());
    OpenCL::Buffer bBuffer = OpenCL::allocateBuffer(ctx, b.data(), sizeof(float), b.size());

    kernel.setArgument(0, aBuffer);
    kernel.setArgument(1, bBuffer);
    kernel.setArgument(2, 2.0f);

    OpenCL::Event saxpy_event = queue.enqueue(kernel, {testDataSize});
    OpenCL::Event read_event = queue.read(bBuffer, b.data(), bBuffer.size());

    std::cout << "SAXPY kernel took " << saxpy_event.getRunTime() << "ns to complete." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Read took " << read_event.getRunTime() << "ns to complete." << std::endl;

    OpenCL::Session::get().cleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

(The profiling won't work because I've disabled it (thinking that was the cause of the problem), re-enabling profiling doesn't fix the issue however).

I'm using CLion, so here's a screenshot of my debugging window:
[image: CLion Debugging Window]

Finally here's the console output of the program:

```
/home/***/cmake-build-debug/Main
[gpu0:0]: AMD - AMD OLAND (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.14.15-1-ARCH, LLVM 5.0.1): 6 compute units @ 825MHz
OpenCL version: OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 17.3.3
Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)
```

The context and device objects all seem to have been created without any issues so I really have no idea what's causing the segfault.

Is it possible that I've found a bug in the Mesa driver, or am I missing something obvious?

**Edit**: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271444/how-to-create-opencl-command-queue) person seems to have had a similar problem, unfortunately, his problem was just a C-style-forget-to-allocate-memory-problem.

**2nd Edit**: I may have found a possible cause of this problem, CMake is finding, using and linking against OpenCL 2.0 while my GPU only supports OpenCL 1.1. I'll look into this.
I haven't found a way to roll back to OpenCL 1.1 on Arch Linux, but clinfo seems to be working fine and so is blender (which depends on OpenCL), so I don't think this is the problem.

Here's the output from clinfo:

```
Number of platforms                               1
  Platform Name                                   Clover
  Platform Vendor                                 Mesa
  Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 17.3.3
  Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd
  Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA

  Platform Name                                   Clover
Number of devices                                 1
  Device Name                                     AMD OLAND (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.14.15-1-ARCH, LLVM 5.0.1)
  Device Vendor                                   AMD
  Device Vendor ID                                0x1002
  Device Version                                  OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 17.3.3
  Driver Version                                  17.3.3
  Device OpenCL C Version                         OpenCL C 1.1 
  Device Type                                     GPU
  Device Available                                Yes
  Device Profile                                  FULL_PROFILE
  Max compute units                               6
  Max clock frequency                             825MHz
  Max work item dimensions                        3
  Max work item sizes                             256x256x256
  Max work group size                             256
  Compiler Available                              Yes
  Preferred work group size multiple              64
  Preferred / native vector sizes                 
    char                                                16 / 16      
    short                                                8 / 8       
    int                                                  4 / 4       
    long                                                 2 / 2       
    half                                                 8 / 8        (cl_khr_fp16)
    float                                                4 / 4       
    double                                               2 / 2        (cl_khr_fp64)
  Half-precision Floating-point support           (cl_khr_fp16)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Single-precision Floating-point support         (core)
    Denormals                                     No
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 No
    Round to infinity                             No
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               No
    Support is emulated in software               No
    Correctly-rounded divide and sqrt operations  No
  Double-precision Floating-point support         (cl_khr_fp64)
    Denormals                                     Yes
    Infinity and NANs                             Yes
    Round to nearest                              Yes
    Round to zero                                 Yes
    Round to infinity                             Yes
    IEEE754-2008 fused multiply-add               Yes
    Support is emulated in software               No
  Address bits                                    64, Little-Endian
  Global memory size                              2147483648 (2GiB)
  Error Correction support                        No
  Max memory allocation                           1503238553 (1.4GiB)
  Unified memory for Host and Device              No
  Minimum alignment for any data type             128 bytes
  Alignment of base address                       32768 bits (4096 bytes)
  Global Memory cache type                        None
  Image support                                   No
  Local memory type                               Local
  Local memory size                               32768 (32KiB)
  Max constant buffer size                        1503238553 (1.4GiB)
  Max number of constant args                     16
  Max size of kernel argument                     1024
  Queue properties                                
    Out-of-order execution                        No
    Profiling                                     Yes
  Profiling timer resolution                      0ns
  Execution capabilities                          
    Run OpenCL kernels                            Yes
    Run native kernels                            No
  Device Extensions                               cl_khr_byte_addressable_store cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_global_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_base_atomics cl_khr_local_int32_extended_atomics cl_khr_int64_base_atomics cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics cl_khr_fp64 cl_khr_fp16

NULL platform behavior
  clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Clover
  clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Success [MESA]
  clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            Success [MESA]
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Clover
    Device Name                                   AMD OLAND (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.14.15-1-ARCH, LLVM 5.0.1)
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Clover
    Device Name                                   AMD OLAND (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.14.15-1-ARCH, LLVM 5.0.1)
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform
  clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  Success (1)
    Platform Name                                 Clover
    Device Name                                   AMD OLAND (DRM 2.50.0 / 4.14.15-1-ARCH, LLVM 5.0.1)

ICD loader properties
  ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader
  ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software
  ICD loader Version                              2.2.12
  ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 2.2
```

**3rd Edit**: I've just run the code on my NVIDIA machine, works without issue, this is what the console shows:

```
[gpu0:0]: NVIDIA Corporation - GeForce GTX 970: 13 compute units @ 1253MHz
OpenCL version: OpenCL 1.2 CUDA 9.1.75
SAXPY kernel took 2368149686ns to complete.
Read took 2368158390ns to complete.
```

I've also fixed the 2 things [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6121044/andreas) mentioned

Comment: Setting CL_QUEUE_PROPERTIES to 0 would be invalid as of the 2.0 spec. You should fix that somehow.

Comment: 2nd note: to capture error use a cl_int type instead of int. if it compiles without error this should not be your problem as of today though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties` got added in OpenCL 2.0. You should not use it with platforms and devices that are less than version 2.0 (such as 1.1 and 1.2 shown in your logs).

Comment: Thank you very much, replacing `clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties` with `clCreateCommandQueue` resolved my issue :D

Comment: Still shouldn't get a SEGFAULT - a simple error with NULL command queue would suffice :)

Answer (score 1):

`clCreateCommandQueue` is deprecated in OpenCL 1.2

It means you can use it both with or without properties.